# How to parse a config file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I've never used `sed` apart from the few hours trying to solve this. I have a config file with parameters like:

```
test.us.param=value
test.eu.param=value
prod.us.param=value
prod.eu.param=value
```

I need to parse these and output this if `REGIONID` is US:

```
test.param=value
prod.param=value
```

Any help on how to do this (with `sed` or otherwise) would be great.

Comment: Could you clarify what REGIONID is or referring to??

Comment: a variable in the script

Comment: So is the idea that the format of the data is somewhat like ENVIRONMENT.REGIONID.param = value  although region id might need to be altered in terms of case?

Just trying to be clear in terms of WHY you are choosing the lines you choose. I think we've all inferred as much but it would enhance the clarity of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
sed -n 's/\.us\././p'
```

i.e. if the ".us." can be replaced by a dot, print the result.

Comment: cool. how can I replace the original four lines in the file with the result rather than just print them?

Comment: @Michael: To change the file in place, use `sed -i~` if supported.

Answer (score 0):

If there are hundreds and hundreds of lines it might be more efficient to first search for lines containing .us. and then do the string replacement... AWK is another good choice or pipe grep into sed

```
cat INPUT_FILE | grep "\.us\." | sed 's/\.us\./\./g'
```

Of course if '.us.' can be in the value this **isn't** sufficient.

You could also do with with the address syntax (technically you can embed the second sed into the first statement as well just can't remember syntax)

```
sed -n '/\(prod\|test\).us.[^=]*=/p' FILE | sed 's/\.us\./\./g'
```

We should probably do something cleaner.  If the format is always environment.region.param we could look at forcing this only to occur on the text PRIOR to the equal sign.

```
sed -n 's/^\([^,]*\)\.us\.\([^=]\)=/\1.\2=/g'
```

This will only work on lines starting with any number of chars followed by '.' then 'us', then '.' and then anynumber prior to '=' sign. This way we won't potentially modify '.us.' if found within a "value"